# Easiest way to install interactive F# compiler?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, f#, f#-interactive

I checked

http://fsharp.org/use/windows/

and especially

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=261286

but I did not find an fsi.exe after installing the latter.

http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/getting-started

does not work for every student and I would prefer to have it on their laptops, being able to use a real editor and save their work.

I gave up on installing a Visual Studio Community Edition, I always end up with several errors:

https://www.visualstudio.com/post-download-vs?sku=community&clcid=0x409&downloadrename=true

For demonstration purposes I would be satisified having a read-eval-print-loop fsi.exe.

What is the easiest way to install it? Does it need background libraries, or it is a standalone binary?

Comment: you might try [visual f # tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48179) but it's really better to install VS2015. As you will need other .net sdks. VSCode with ionide works also well.

Comment: What errors do you get when you install VS Community Edition?

Comment: @TomasPetricek Universal CRT Headers Libraries and Sources -- Package failed. Windows SDK Package failed Windows App Certification Kit x86 user stopped installation (I did not stop it at all) Windows App Certification Kit Native Components -- user stopped installation Windows Runtime Intellisense Content - en-us -- user stopped installation Windows Software Development Kit Package failed Windows Software Development Kit DirectX x86 Remote (I copy this from a screenshot, the last line is hidden)

Comment: that's really a bunch of errors... Usual steps apply, use admin privilege, update your windows to latest, disable virus scan. From [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#latestreleases/) you can get the ISO image or a web installer. By the way do you also need the C++ libraries (CRT)? It's going to download the whole interweb....